# Summarizing Bayesian rating formula

Tags: algorithm, bayesian

Based on this url i found [Bayesian Rating](http://www.thebroth.com/blog/118/bayesian-rating), which explains the rating model very well, i wanted to summarize the formula to make it much easier for anyone implementing an SQL statement. Would this be correct if i summarized the formula like this?

```
avg_num_votes  = Sum(votes)/Count(votes) * Count(votes)

avg_rating     = sum(votes)/count(votes)

this_num_votes = count(votes)

this_rating    = Positive_votes - Negative_votes
```

Gath

Comment: avg_num_votes  = Sum(votes)/Count(votes) * Count(votes)
this makes no sence if Count(votes)=Count(votes).

Comment: Without knowing much about Bayesian ratinng, I'd say probably not. To start with, your avg_num_votes is exactly equal to Sum(votes), which doesn't sound like what the variable should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would look more like this:

```
avg_num_votes  = Count(votes)/Count(items with at least 1 vote)
avg_rating     = Sum(votes)/Count(items with at least 1 vote)

this_num_votes = Count(votes for this item)
this_rating    = Sum(votes for this item)/Count(votes for this item)
```

If you are using a simple +/- system, `Sum(votes) = Count(positive votes)` (ie. treat + as 1, - as 0)

See also: [Bayesian average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average).

Answer (score 0):

Should the avg_rating not be:

Sum(votes)/Count(votes)

Yves